# How to get an unprivileged public status page showing in OpenWrt 12.09 or newer?

Tags: openwrt

For the use case where the WAN connection goes down, but employees can still access wifi, I'd like them to be able to check on some sort of a public router status page in their problem reports. This may have been available on DD-WRT at one point (or still is), I can't 100% recall anymore.

Going through all LuCI's screens with a fine-toothed comb and googling a fair amount isn't producing results. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DD-WRT had a public status page (which can be a security risk); OpenWrt does not.

However, [LuCI does have an API](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/JsonRpcHowTo), so you could write your own status page pretty quickly, and secure it properly.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm maybe there's a way to take LuCI's status screen code and strip it down something less risky but still useful. Good pointer to the API.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved easily but can be a threat to your netwrok security (eg: The client MAC addresses are not masked). Better use Michael Hampton's suggestion to create your own status page with the API.

1. Create /usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/overview.lua

   ```
   module("luci.controller.overview", package.seeall)

   function index()
       assign({"overview"}, {"admin", "status", "overview"}, nil)
   end
   ```
2. Run `rm -rf /tmp/luci-indexcache /tmp/luci-modulecache/`
3. Logout from luci interface
4. Visit `http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/luci/overview` (change the IP according to your setup)
5. Add `/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/overview.lua` to `/etc/sysupgrade.conf` so it survives upgrades

Anyway, you can always strip down/modify the admin->status->overview page Lua codes and add it to a new public page. Adding new pages on Luci web interface is also quite easy.

More info:

- https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/luci/statistics.chart.public
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/43665026/4040525
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/19708316/4040525
- http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2018/01/adding-new-elements-to-openwrts-luci-on.html
- https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/luci